# Data flow GUI library for data traveling between few sites

Tags: user-interface, charts, dataflow

as the title suggest, I wanted to know if there's a ready-to-use GUI library that provide with a kind of data flow chart. Since this issue of displaying data flow is common in a lot a fields, I think there's a good chance that there is something available, it's just that I didn't find it.

It would be better if it'll be open source in C++, but anything goes...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ugene Workflow Designer [[1](http://ugene.unipro.ru/documentation/manual/plugins/workflow_designer.html)]  is an opensource c++ program